# Hyperledger Fabric gRPC Length Limit, Timeout for Application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running a chaincode application that basically returns a lot of historical versions (getHistoryForKey for a range of keys). I am running that chaincode over the 3 million key:value pair inserted into ledger. I am using HLF 2.3.3.

Chaincode execution fails with the following error:

```
[fabsdk/core] 2023/08/16 03:22:32 UTC - cryptosuite.GetDefault -> INFO No default cryptosuite found, using default SW implementation
[fabsdk/fab] 2023/08/16 03:25:29 UTC - peer.(*peerEndorser).sendProposal -> ERRO process proposal failed [rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (122477059 vs. 104857600)]
[fabsdk/fab] 2023/08/16 03:25:30 UTC - peer.(*peerEndorser).sendProposal -> ERRO process proposal failed [rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (122477059 vs. 104857600)]
2023/08/15 21:25:30 Failed to evaluate transaction: Failed to evaluate: Multiple errors occurred: - Transaction processing for endorser [localhost:9051]: gRPC Transport Status Code: (8) ResourceExhausted. Description: grpc: received message larger than max (122477059 vs. 104857600) - Transaction processing for endorser [localhost:7051]: gRPC Transport Status Code: (8) ResourceExhausted. Description: grpc: received message larger than max (122477059 vs. 104857600)
exit status 1
```

I believe it happens because the query result is more then 100Mb. What should I change to make it actually work? There are files like core.yaml, configtx.yaml, etc, how should I modify them to change the 100MB limitation?

Also if I am trying to execute the same chaincode query, but for a 4 million inserted key:value pairs, chaincode execution breaks with timeout error after executing it for about 180 seconds. How to fix/change that timeout?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC is not designed for very large message sizes. In a bespoke application you could use gRPC server streaming to stream larger sets of data back to a client as a series of smaller messages - this is actually how block and chaincode eventing are implemented in Fabric - but Fabric uses simple request/response messaging for transaction invocation so this is not an option here.

I think there are two obvious approaches you can take:

1. Don't deal with such large chunks of data; or
2. Deal with those large chunks of data outside of Fabric.

To reduce the data size, you might consider having a single transaction invocation operate over only a subset of the data. To get all the data back, the client would need to invoke the transaction function multiple times, each time providing arguments to indicate what portion of the data (or results) are to be retrieved.

If you must deal with the data in one go, or perhaps need a more performant mechanism for indexing and processing large portions of ledger data, you could use an off-chain data store. Since this is your own data store, holding a replica of the ledger data, you can use whatever tools are appropriate for your use-case to store and access the data. See the [off_chain_data](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data) sample for an example of how to use block eventing to build and maintain an off-chain data store.

If you really do need to change the default gRPC message size limit in the Fabric, there is a [setting in the node configuration](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6fefd7242fc44ea87018abe3545fab9ff74b87be/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L496-L501). Using the Fabric Gateway client API, you might need to change the [Gateway peer service endorsementTimeout](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6fefd7242fc44ea87018abe3545fab9ff74b87be/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L53-L55) too. In your client application, you probably need to configure the maximum receive message size on your client gRPC connection. Using the Go API, One of the [DialOptions](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#DialOption) you can supply when creating the gRPC client connection is `WithDefaultCallOptions`, which allows you to set a default `MaxCallRecvMsgSize`. You can also provide specific gRPC CallOptions on any of the calls (for example, [Endorse](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway/pkg/client#Proposal.Evaluate)) in the [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/).

Comment: Thank you for your response!
May I ask what happens when HLF comes to production environment where 10 million of data records are and someone wants to get all historical values for a range of keys? What would be the recommended practice? Using off chain data? I am asking out of the curiosity since I have a feeling (most likely incorrect) that HLF is not good for data history operations.

Other than that just for testing/research purposes, is there a way to overwrite the gRPC message size as well as a query timeout?

Comment: There is a gRPC message size limit in the Fabric node config (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6fefd7242fc44ea87018abe3545fab9ff74b87be/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L496-L501). Using the Fabric Gateway client API, you may need to change the Gateway service endorsementTimeout too (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/6fefd7242fc44ea87018abe3545fab9ff74b87be/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L53-L55). Depending on your client implementation language, you might need to configure the maximum receive message size on your client gRPC connection.

Comment: I have already tried to change things you mentioned in ```core.yaml``` : ```maxRecvMsgSize```, ```maxSendMsgSize```, ```endorsementTimeout```. Probably I need to configure maximum receive message size on my client gRPC connection. I am using GO lang, can you please tell where to change it?

Comment: One of the DialOptions you can supply when creating the gRPC client connection is WithDefaultCallOptions, which allows you to set a default MaxCallRecvMsgSize (https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#DialOption). You can also provide gRPC CallOptions on any of the calls in the Fabric Gateway client API.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, "How should I modify them to change the 100MB limitation?", this [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/config_update.html?highlight=config.json#step-1-pull-and-translate-the-config) will be helpful. Basically, you need to adjust "absolute_max_bytes, max_message_count," and "preferred_max_bytes". According to the instructions from that link,you can reconfigure the value and do not need to stop the network.

Besides,for your second question, "How to fix or change that timeout?" I think it is the same way to change, although I have not tried it (I tried to change the three values mentioned above and succeeded), and I guess that all you need to do is change "BatchTimeout", which maybe can answer your second question.